# Вывести массив по порядку в ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Как в angular добиться вывода массива по порядку в select через ng-options.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="foo" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myArray">
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/51sa4vsj/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае используется форма для работы с объектом и массив рассматривается как объект ключами "0", "1" ...
Так как ключи это строки - они отсортированы как строки.

Для решения - нужно использовать форму для массива.
Кроме того сортировка полей объекта была убрана после версии 1.3 или 1.4

например:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]).controller("MyCtrl",['$scope',MyCtrl]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 5;
    $scope.foo2 = "5";
    $scope.myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <select ng-model="foo" ng-options="v for v in myArray"></select>
  
  {{foo}}
  
  <select ng-model="foo2" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in myArray"></select>
  {{foo2}}
</div>
```